# Is it okay to have irrelevant text in paragraph tags?

Tags: seo, html5, content

My Magento site and theme has a total of 30 paragraphs (`<p>`) in the source code of the product page.  Only 5 are relevant to the product.  Others include the the welcome message, phone number, back to top message, address in footer, etc.  What is the best SEO practice in terms of having irrelevant content in paragraph tags?  Should I consider turning some of the paragraph tags into `<div>` tags?  If you have an answer, I would appreciate supporting information.

Additionally, I've read that `<hgroup>` tags are dead so I began looking at `<article>`/`<header>` tags, however, I am wondering if those are for news/blogs only.  Is there a product equivalent to `<article>`?

Comment: Each post should only contain one question. Your questions about `p`/`div` and `article/`etc. aren’t really related, so you should ideally remove the last paragraph and create a separate question post for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags help identify the type of content and that is all, ignoring styling. Text is text in every case so changing the element from a `<p>` to a `<div>` won't affect SEO.

Irrelevant content is wasted space. Remove irrelevant content.

`<hgroup>` is [a standard element in the HTML5 specification](https://developers.whatwg.org/sections.html#the-hgroup-element). At one time, it had been removed but that's no longer true so it's not dead.